# Zoom in and zoom out functionality in jquery mobile or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there any good way for zoom in and zoom out functionality in a page using jQuery mobile. I goggled it and found

```js
window.parent.document.body.style.zoom = 1.5;
```

Is there any better way to do zoom in and zoom out functionality in jQuery mobile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample workaround, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/aGuLE/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#zoomIn').on('click', function () {
        zoomIn(1.2);
    });
    $('#zoomOut').on('click', function () {
        zoomOut();
    });
});

function zoomIn(zoomLev) {
    if (zoomLev > 1) {
        if (typeof (document.body.style.zoom) != "undefined") {
            $(document.body).css('zoom', zoomLev);
        }else {
            // Mozilla doesn't support zoom, use -moz-transform to scale and compensate for lost width
            $('#divWrap').css({
                "-moz-transform": 'scale(" + zoomLev + ")',
                width: $(window).width() / zoomLev
            });
        }
    }
}

function zoomOut() {
    $(document.body).css({
        zoom : '',
        position : '',
        left: "",
        top: "",
        "-moz-transform" : "",
        width : ''  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery mobile you need to check your the meta data in `<head>` of your file

`<meta name="viewport"
 content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />`

if `content="user-scalable=no` is defined in your viewport metadata this will prevent you from scaling or zooming in and out

Comment: can you please give me any example..?

Comment: you just need to check your html page mainly you need to check what is found inside  the <head></head> attribute if there is a <meta> attribute that contains <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no," just remove the attribute user-scalable=no , remove this and zooming should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You must have already a meta viewport somewhere.

```
var viewportmeta=$("meta[name='viewport']"); //find a viewport meta

viewportmeta.attr("content_original", viewportmeta.attr("content")); //store the initial value
viewportmeta.attr("content", "user-scalable=yes, width=device-width minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"); //make current viewport full zoom out

//do your things... 

viewportmeta.attr("content", viewportmeta.attr("content_original")); //then return back to old  viewport conditions
```