# Revert back to full screen after inputting selection on Mobile

Tags: html, css

I have an option to select a wireless carrier from a list - the problem is that Iphone "zooms in" when creating the selectable dropdown list similar to this:

http://winmobiletech.com/012009Browsers/IMG_0017.PNG

My code is as follows:

```
<div id="popup-action-sms" style="display:none" >
        <div id="sms" >
            <input type="number" id="sms-tel" placeholder="Enter phone number" />
            <select id="sms-carriers">
                <option value="" >Select Wireless Carrier</option>
                <option value="Alltel">Alltel</option>
                <option value="AT&T">AT&T</option>
                <option value="Sprint">Sprint</option>
                <option value="T-Mobile">T-Mobile</option>
                <option value="Verizon Wireless">Verizon Wireless</option>
            </select>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="sms-submit">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**My question** How can I dynamically "zoom out" back to full screen once a user has selected their carrier?

Comment: Take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29352162/2542172)

Comment: Bit of a newbie when it comes to java - how and where would I implement this?

Comment: [Let us continue this discussion in chat.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174467/add-a-js-to-html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#sms-carriers" ).change(function() {
     $(this).blur();
});
```

You can also try $(this).focusout();

Worth giving a shot :)