# Since viewport changes have now been disabled, how can I force a viewport 'unzoom' with javascript?

Tags: javascript, viewport, scaling, pinchzoom

I've implemented a scheme allowing visitors on my website to tap small photos to see a larger view. The tap/click causes a new page element to appear and expand to the max dimensions available for the screen, displaying a higher resolution image there. The reason is to avoid loading high bandwidth images unless the visitor is interested. Once the better hi-resolution image is displayed, the visitor can further expand the image with finger pinch gestures, as its typical for phones. The problem is, if the visitor does manually enlarge the photo, they will be left with an annoying oversized page after dismissing the larger image. And no matter what I do, the visitor's manual adjustment of the image affects the whole page.

For a long time there was a reasonable solution to this, which I found years ago somewhere here on stack exchange. I'd set up a function like this...

```
function resetScreenSize() {
    var viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
    if(viewport===null){
        // just for test alert("no viewport meta");
        return;
        }

    var original = viewport.getAttribute('content');
    var forceScale = original+",maximum-scale=1.0";
    viewport.setAttribute('content', forceScale); 
    setTimeout(function() {
        viewport.setAttribute("content", original);
        }, 100);
    
    }
```

The idea was to un-do whatever manual zooming the visitor did by adding the "maximum-scale" value of 1 to the viewport, wait a moment for system to settle, and then return the viewport to its original settings (without a maximum scale). After testing this approach with a simple button, I just set up my code to call the function automatically when the visitor dismissed the zoomed image.

Well it seems that Apple, in their infinite wisdom, has decided that IOS devices will no longer honor viewport "maximum-scale", as well as several other options, like disallowing user scaling. It seems to be blocked on other browsers too like Chrome on IOS. So as a result my scheme no longer works. If a visitor picks a full size image and then expands it further, I have no way to set the viewport back to normal, without doing something drastic like re-loading the page.

I've tried a few other approaches I've found on stackexchange, most involving attempts to block zooming to begin with. That's not what I want.

So is there another solution I could consider? I know Social media giants like Facebook have a way of letting a visitor click an image to bring up a larger view, and no matter how the visitor enlarges it manually, things go back to normal once the photo is dismissed. But I don't know how that do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran in a similar problem a while back and [fixed it in a similar way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639296/force-mobile-browser-zoom-out-with-javascript/46137189#46137189).

One important trick here was the wait with a 100ms. Using 0 would get the code executed immediately and not actually apply anything.

Now, if Apple changed the rules on these viewport parameters (probably because it got abused by some), then one solution I can think of is to use an IFRAME. I think that Facebook uses that technique whenever they open a "popup" with an image in it (and comments on the side). That makes it really easy to close that *window* and get back to the previous view. Also the viewport scaling factor will be changed in the IFRAME and not the window in the back. So you should get exactly what's necessary.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because its very close to a solution that I now know works, because of your suggestion. The difference is that I've done it with a separate window I open (not an Iframe), passing a url, which contains the url of a special page, along with parameters (the URL of the photo, caption, colors, etc). When the window opens, I parse the url to get the data, and create an IMG that takes up the full screen. A body "onclick" is also set up which closes the window. So the visitor can pinch zoom, and tap to dismiss the window when done.

Comment: On mobile chrome it is almost seamless, since the new window comes right into view. On mobile safari you see the new page flip up into view, but it still works. IFRAMEs I'm a little skeptical of, but I'll need to experiment. So far in all the IFRAME demos I've found, pinch zooming still seems to affect both the IFRAME as well as the parent screen, whice is what I wanted to avoid. Right track though. If you're interested, email me using the address I sent you privately, and I'll send you a site with my current progress.

Comment: I think that using a separate window can be problematic on a Desktop because there it will open a new tab which is not the same as an IFRAME. That being said, if your visitors are mainly on smartphones, then it certainly doesn't matter much.

Comment: I detect (or at least try to) when the visitor is using a mobile device, and in that case don't enable the feature. Its not necessary because the first step happens when you click a thumbnail, which causes a hi-def version to expand the the window limits, which is usually big enough. On desktop the second click just returns the photo to normal. On mobile phones, a second click within 2 seconds causes the new-window version. Good enough for now, but if I discover that an i-frame can (1) go full screen (2) allow pinch zoom, and (3) the pinch zoom won't distort the original page, I'll switch!

Comment: Too late to edit, but I actually meant the opposite of my first sentence in the comment above. It is in the NON mobile case (like a desktop with a large screen) when i DON'T enable the feature. Should make more sense now.